# Wp die causing 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, settings-api

I have function to upload images inside my settings API ,it uploads images as expected but the problem comes when user chooses to upload **non-image file** to stop users from uploading other files (non-image files) i am using `wp_die('No image found');` an that leads to dreaded
**500 Internal Server Error** message displayed. Strange thing is that my wp_die `wp_die('No image found');` is running fine on my **local computer** but not **online**.

```
function validate_setting($plugin_options){ 

  //echo '<pre>';  print_r($_FILES); echo '</pre>';
  $keys = array_keys($_FILES);
   $i = 0;
  foreach ($_FILES as $image) {        

if($image['size']){
    //Is it an image?
    if(preg_match('/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i',$image['type'])){
      $override = array('test_form' => false);
      $file = wp_handle_upload($image,$override);         
      $plugin_options[$keys[$i]] = $file['url'];
    }
   else{
   wp_die('No image found');//This triggers 500 Internal Server Error WHY??
       //echo:'no image found'; //Now this DON'T work locally but works ONLINE?!?
   }
}
else{
 $options = get_option('theme_options');
 $plugin_options[$keys[$i]] = $options[$keys[$i]];
}
$i++;
    } 
    return $plugin_options;
    }
```

I tried to change `wp_die()` to `echo 'no image found';` and this happens:
now on my **locall** machine it echoes 'nothing' (no warning displayed), but now **online** it works and displays 'no image found' warning...

I know i could simply delete the `else{
       wp_die('No image found');
           }` part and display no warning, but WHY it is not working as intended?

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code and how to display warning with wp_die('No image found') properly *(without causing "500 Internal server error" )*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `die($msg);` to do what you're trying to do. [wp_die()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) returns an HTTP error code and passes your message to the error page, and the default code is 500 (internal server error) if you don't set the return code in the args.

Comment: Thx buddy!! Hats off...

Answer (score 3):

This worked really nice for me:

```
 else{
   $error = new WP_Error( 'not_found', _('No image found! Please upload images only!'), 
        array( 'title' => _('Plugin Error'), 'response' => '406', 'back_link' => true ) );
        if( is_wp_error($error) ){
        wp_die( $error, '', $error->get_error_data() ); 
        }
   }
```